# How to host and connect to a net.tcp service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, net.tcp, self-hosting

I need to code from scratch a WCF service with net.tcp binding, self-hosted on IIS7, and call it from a console application. Can you give me a step-by-step guide for the service and for the sample client application?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following guides and tutorials:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPrQPA9QmUw

Answer (score 0):

How about this little [Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx) from Microsoft?